# Looking for a router-like web interface for my Debian gateway

Tags: router, debian, port-forwarding, gateway, administration

Hey, I need a web interface program for my debian gateway which has the features of a router's one. Specifically, I must be able to **easily**

- Forward ports to various clients on the LAN or the router itself (it's also a server)
- Manage a DHCP server preferably including DHCP reservation for certain MACs
- Give me a list of the connected DHCP clients
- (optionally) Show which clients are the most active as far as bandwidth (something like iftop)

Alternatively, it could be a graphical app which I could tunnel over ssh. No command line programs please...I'm used to doing this stuff with a point-and-click interface. Not adverse to command-line setup; just need to be able to reconfigure things graphically. Have a working LAMP setup.

I've tried webmin, but it didn't satisfy the "easy" part...too many clicks and too many meny options.